# What's the best way to generate unique permutations in Python?

Tags: python, random, combinations, sequence, combinatorics

I have 2 choices between 0 and 1 for each item where I will have N elements sequenced one after another generating a unique combination.

So something like these (sequence length=10):

```
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
```

As you see these are all unique permutations. I will have 10000 of these permutations (for example). But the key info is I don't need all the permutations, but rather only save a limited set of them, and ideally out of order, so it's a bit more "random".

My current solution is to generate random numbers between 0 and 1, and append them in an array up to N elements. Then turn this array into a string and if this string is not already added to my list above, then add this, otherwise repeat the same step to generate a different permutation.

So that means using a while loop.

Is there a smarter, or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's you upvoting the answers below within seconds of being posted, but whoever reads this should know that link-only answer do not warrant the "This answer is useful" vote

Comment: Note that for sequence length 10, you'll only have 2^10 = 1024 unique combinations. But I guess these are just example values

Comment: Thanks yes I have more than 10 items, I just wanted to give some simple examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This is a binary number and each unique binary number correspond to a
  unique decimal.
- With 10 places, there are 2^10 = 1024 unique.
- Choose 10 from these 1024 without replacement
- Convert decimal to its binary

Generate 5 unique samples each of 10 digits

```
import numpy as np
n_digits = 10
n_sample = 5
for c in np.random.choice(np.power(2,n_digits), size=n_sample, replace=False):
  c = int("{0:b}".format(c))
  print (str(c).zfill(n_digits))
```

Sample run

```
0100011110
0110110011
0100110001
1110011100
1110101011
```

#### Edit:

The above code is fast but will not scale to larger digits due to `np.power(2,n_digits)` resulting in overflow as well `np.random.choice` will run out of memory.

For scaling it to very large sequences we can use a bit slow but very decent mechanism like below

```
n_digits = 200
n_sample = 10000
choices = []
cache = {}
while len(choices) < n_sample:
    c = np.random.randint(0,2,(n_digits))
    k = c.tostring()
    if not k in cache:
        cache[k] = True
        choices.append(c)
```

`%timeit` returned

```
27.4 ns ± 10.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

which is pretty decent.

`choices` is list of numpy arrays and if you want to convert it into text you can use

```
for i in range(len(choices)):
    choices[i] = np.array2string(choices[i], separator='')[1:-1].replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: When I run this, I am getting values like this: 1111101110
1001101
11011000
110010000
1110110101
1010111000
1111011111
1110110111
111000101
11110010, not all of them have 10 digits, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you edit it? I might have to use your answer because I need this to scale.

Comment: I get syntax error on the last line, not sure if that's valid?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now. How do you control how many items to get in total vs how man digits to have? I changed size to 20, but it still showed 10 digits, I don't know if there is a way to control these.

Comment: Updated. Control via `n_digits` and `n_samples`

Comment: I just find a bug when I set n_digits = 200
n_sample = 10000, it errored out mtrand.pyx choice function = a must be greater than 0.

Comment: 2^200 results in overflows :(

Comment: Oh I see, ok I will try to figure out a different method :)

Comment: @JoanVenge edited answer with a different solution for very large sequences

Comment: Thanks a lot the new method works better. One thing though not sure why I tried your printing and also I sliced the choice without using your formatting like str(choice[i])[1:-1] but it when it's still breaking down the array into multiple lines for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out using this: ' '.join(map(str, choice))